# How to use this function based Event Emitter?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, eventemitter

In [this old answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/150851) is there the below function based event emitter.

Maybe it is super obvious how to use it, but not for me, so I would really appreciate if someone could make a hello world example with it.

Can anyone figure out how to use it?

```
function EventBase() {
  this.events = {};
};

EventBase.prototype = {
  on: function (event, listener) {
    if (typeof event !== 'string') throw new TypeError("Event must be a string");
    if (typeof event !== 'string') throw new TypeError("Listener must be a function");
    this.events[event] || (this.events[event] = []);
    this.events[event].push(listener);
  },

  off: function (event, listener) {
    if (arguments.length === 0) {
      // remove all listeners
      this.events = {};
      return;
    }

    if (!this.events[event]) {
      // return if there's no event by the given name
      return;
    }

    if (arguments.length === 1) {
      // remove all listeners for the given event
      delete this.events[event];
      return;
    }

    // remove specific listener
    this.events[event] = this.events[event].filter(function (func) {
      return func !== listener;
    });
  },

  emit: function (event) {
    if (!this.events[event]) {
      // return if there's no event by the given name
      return;
    }

    // get args
    var args = [].slice.call(arguments, 1);

    // invoke listeners
    this.events[event].forEach(listener => listener.apply(this, args));
  },

  getListenerCount: function (event) {
    // get total number of listeners
    if (arguments.length === 0) {
      return Object.keys(this.events).reduce((count, key) => count + this.getListenerCount(key), 0);
    }

    // return zero for non-existing events
    if (!this.events[event]) {
      return 0;
    }

    // return count for specific event
    return this.events[event].length;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EventBase is a constructor function. After we instantiate it, we can call the methods defined in the prototype. `on` method allows you to add a listener callback to a certain event name. `emit` allows to emit an event name, which will then trigger the listener listening for that event

```
const event = new EventBase()

event.on("connect", () => {
  console.log("connected")
})

event.emit("connect")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot =) Is it possible to make it into a module, so I can `const EventBase = require('./EventBase')` ?

Comment: Of course, you just need to export it. In the file that defined `EventBase`, add `export default EventBase` to the end of the file, then you can import and use it else where

Comment: When I do that I get `SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'`

Comment: `module.exports = EventBase;` did the trick =)